# Core data migration after changing model

Tags: ios, core-data

I have changed my Core Data model a while back and found out after weeks that it causes a crash on older versions of the app. I get the error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model."
```

My issue is that I don't remember changing anything in my model and have no idea what is causing the migration problem. Is there any way for me to find this out, or have a look at the the model from the older version?

(My project was not under version control at this time.)

Comment: If you do model migration, the older versions of the model should still be in the app.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I deleted the app from the simulator or physical device and installed it back.

Answer (score 1):

You're not likely to know what you changed. 
My guess is you did edits on the one existing model version and since it was installed with the previous version of that same model - Core Data crashes.

In that case, there's nothing you can really do. Just catch the error when it's thrown by persistent store coordinator, remove the store from said URL and add a new one.

```
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL)
} catch let error {        
    print("Error adding persistent store: \(error). Will try with a new one.")
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: storeURL)
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL)
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Failed creating new persistent store with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

And add and use git in your project - it's super easy and extremely useful, even if you don't host the sources on GitHub or any other repository hosting - just for situations like this one.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea on how should I go about removing the store and adding a new one? I

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Does not really matter, but preferably Swift. :)

Comment: Added an example in Swift - hope it helps.